# How to avoid fringes?

Tags: artifacts, color-fringing

What can I do avoid fringes around a subject in my pictures?

My camera is a bridge camera (namely a fujifilm hsr20).

Comment: what sort of fringes? Under what conditions? You will need to upload an example image e.g. to imgur.com and post a link in order to answer your question

Comment: Hi harini and welcome to the site. Are you interested in removing these artifacts while taking the picture or in post processing only?

Comment: You now have enough upvotes that you can upload an image here directly.

Answer (score 2):

Some fringing is a result of overexposure. What happens is that the light shining on the sensor builds up a charge, and the charge sort of leaks to neighboring sensor elements. This produces a fringing around bright objects, for example, a picture of an egret standing in front of a dark background. The solution in this case is to lower the exposure.

Some fringing is the result of chromatic aberration in the lens used. In that case, the solutions are using a different lens or using software (such as Lightroom or Photoshop) that can correct chromatic aberration.

Answer (score 0):

Fringing generally is an artifact of the lens you are using.  So here are a few approaches to reduction of fringing:

1. Buy a good lens.  The better lenses reduce fringing and CA artifacts
   quite a bit with advanced coatings.  However be aware that generally
   the wider aperture a lens has, the more fringing is possible with a
   lens (so an f/1.4 lens is generally going to exhibit some fringing
   at times no matter how good it is).
2. Stop down.  Fringing is much stronger wide open, as you stop down it
   reduces the strength of the effect.
3. Shoot RAW.  Conversion software often has some good CA reduction you
   can use to get rid of some fringing.